# The earliest assertion in Christianity that abiding in Christ is only possible through Eucharist

Tags: communion

When was the first statement made and by whom in Christianity that abiding in Christ is only possible through Eucharist?

I only found such statement made by Cyprian. Was there anyone who said the same prior to him?

Comment: If possible, please cite what Cyprian said.